# What does `features['contains(%s)' % word.lower()] = True` mean in NLTK?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, nlp, nltk

I've been reading nltk document recently.And I don't understand the following code.

```
def dialogue_act_features(post):
    features = {}
    for word in nltk.word_tokenize(post):
        features['contains(%s)' % word.lower()] = True
    return features
```

This is a feature extractor for NaiveBayesClassifier,but what does

`features['contains(%s)' % word.lower()] = True`

mean?

I think this line of code is a way to generate a dict,but I have no idea how it works.

Thanks

Comment: yep, it checks for a key present or not in a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> def word_features(sentence):
...     features = {}
...     for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sentence):
...         features['contains(%s)' % word.lower()] = True
...     return features
...     
...    
... 
>>> sent = 'This a foobar word extractor function'
>>> word_features(sent)
{'contains(a)': True, 'contains(word)': True, 'contains(this)': True, 'contains(function)': True, 'contains(extractor)': True, 'contains(foobar)': True}
>>>
```

This line is trying to populate/fill up a features dictionary.:

```
features['contains(%s)' % word.lower()] = True
```

Here's a simple example of dictionary in python (see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries for details):

```
>>> adict = {}
>>> adict['key'] = 'value'
>>> adict['key']
'value'
>>> adict['apple'] = 'red'
>>> adict['apple']
'red'
>>> adict
{'apple': 'red', 'key': 'value'}
```

And `word.lower()` lowercase a string, e.g.

```
>>> str = 'Apple'
>>> str.lower()
'apple'
>>> str = 'APPLE'
>>> str.lower()
'apple'
>>> str = 'AppLe'
>>> str.lower()
'apple'
```

And when you do `'contains(%s)' % word` it's trying to create string `contain(` and a sign operator and then a `)`. The sign operator will be assigned outside the string, e.g.

```
>>> a = 'apple'
>>> o = 'orange'
>>> '%s' % a
'apple'
>>> '%s and' % a
'apple and'
>>> '%s and %s' % (a,o)
'apple and orange'
```

The sign operator is similar to the `str.format()` function e.g.

```
>>> a = 'apple'
>>> o = 'orange'
>>> '%s and %s' % (a,o)
'apple and orange'
>>> '{} and {}'.format(a,o)
'apple and orange'
```

So when the code does `'contains(%s)' % word` it's actually trying to produce a string like this:

```
>>> 'contains(%s)' % a
'contains(apple)'
```

And when you put that string into a dictionary as your key, your key will look as such:

```
>>> adict = {}
>>> key1 = 'contains(%s)' % a
>>> value1 = True
>>> adict[key1] = value1
>>> adict
{'contains(apple)': True}
>>> key2 = 'contains(%s)' % o
>>> value = 'orange'
>>> value2 = False
>>> adict[key2] = value2
>>> adict
{'contains(orange)': False, 'contains(apple)': True}
```

For more information, see

- [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Answer (score 2):

Say `word='ABCxyz'`,

`word.lower()` ---> would convert it into lower case so it returns `abcxyz'`

`'contains(%s)' % word.lower()` ---> would format the string and replace `%s` with the value of `word.lower()` and returns `'contains(abcxyz)'`

`features['contains(%s)' % word.lower()] = True` --->would create a key-value pair in features dictionary with key as `'contains(abcxyz)'` and value as `True`

Thus,

```
features = {}
features['contains(%s)' % word.lower()] = True
```

would create

```
features = {'contains(abcxyz)':True}
```

Comment: there's a minor mistake in your final feature dictionary. should be `features{contains('abcxyz'): True)`.